# Django - Unable to Redirect to Update Form and Update Values

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, primary-key

I've prepared a django app that would take input from user after the user logs in. Once the user logs in they can input values to form and post it to db. However, I need to provide user the capability to update the already existing entry based on conjugate primary key `Station` and `Date`. I've added a `update` button on page `form` to update entry in case if user inputs values for already existing primary key.

I need to achieve two things

- Enable update button only if user inputs values for already existing primary key.
- Though update button is enabled but I am unable to redirect to `update_form` page.

Currently I am unable to figure out why can't I redirect to `update_form` page. I am getting following error
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_form' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\\^\\(\\?P(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\[0\\-9\\]\\+\\)/update_form/\\$$']`

Following are all relevant scripts being used:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class ManHour(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('date', 'station'),)

    station_choices = (
       ('KHI','Karachi'),
       ('ISB', 'Islamabad'),
       ('LHE','Lahore'),
       )

    station = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=station_choices,
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    date_time  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    imports_airside = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
    imports_landside = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
    exports = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from .form import InputForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from manhourapp.models import ManHour
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError  
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect('form')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request = request,
                    template_name = "login.html",
                    context={"form":form})



@login_required(login_url='login')
def form_page(request):
    context = {}
    try:
        man_hour = ManHour.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get("pk"))
    except ManHour.DoesNotExist:
        man_hour = None

    if man_hour:
        context["Total_Imports"] = man_hour.imports_airside + man_hour.imports_landside
    if man_hour:
        context["Total_Hours"] = man_hour.imports_airside + man_hour.imports_landside + man_hour.exports

    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            obj = properties_Form.save()
            return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('form'), obj.pk))
        else:
            context['form'] = properties_Form
            return render(request, "form.html", context)
    else:
        context['form']= InputForm(instance=man_hour)
        return render(request, "form.html", context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def update_form(request, pk):
    man_hour = ManHour.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = InputForm(instance=man_hour)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            obj = properties_Form.save()
            return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('update_form'), obj.pk))

    else:
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'update_form.html', context)
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from manhourapp.models import ManHour
from datetime import date

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['date','station', 'imports_airside', 'imports_landside', 'exports']
        widgets = {
            'date':forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'max':str(date.today())})
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from pages import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login_request, name='login'),
    path('form/', views.form_page, name='form'),
    path('update_form/<int:pk_>/', views.update_form, name='update_form'),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),

]
```

**form.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      

        <form target="upload_frame" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}<br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Imports" value="{{ Total_Imports }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Hours" value="{{ Total_Hours }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="update_form/<int:pk_>">Update</a>
            <div class="user_panel">
                <a href="/logout">logout</a>
            </div>
        </form>           
    </body>
</html>
```

**update_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      

        <form target="upload_frame" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ update_form.as_p }}<br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Imports" value="{{ Total_Imports }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Hours" value="{{ Total_Hours }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
            <div class="user_panel">
                <a href="/logout">logout</a>
            </div>
        </form>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first redirect you have to type 'reverse' before calling url name.

And instead of

```
return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('update_form'), obj.pk))
```

try

```
return redirect(reverse('update_form', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk}
```

Comment: I am getting an error page not found `The current path, form/update_form/<int:pk_>, didn't match any of these urls.`

Comment: Try to delete action="." in your <form />